# Why is my Javascript console showing a 404 error for a file called "null" on a clean Wordpress install?

Tags: 404-error

Every Wordpress site I am building shows *404 (Not Found)* error in the Javascript console for a file called *null*. I have confirmed that this happening on a clean install of WP 5.9.3 without any plugins, settings changes, or database edits. Here's what it looks like in Chrome Dev console:

[image: screenshot of javascript console 404 error for null]

This happens on every page on the site whether I am logged in or not. In the above example, if you look at the referenced line 330, it's always a blank line at the end of the rendered HTML:

[image: the supposedly bad line of code]

What is causing this error?

Comment: Did you try visiting your permalinks section in settings and then visiting the frontpage again?

Comment: I just tried that. It seems to remove the error for anonymous users (good!) but it remains there if I am logged in.

Comment: That's strange.  Could be caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was being caused by a Chrome browser extension. I use an extension installed called "CrxMouse Chrome Gestures." This extension is the cause of this error. I have turned off the extension and notified the author of this bug.